# MVC 5 Unity Constructor Injection Failing/Returning Null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I have the below code that is returning null when I try and return Sales Data.  It works if I remove the other constructor for employee, so I believe it is a constructor injection issue.

How do I handle this injection?

Repository: Located in a seperate Project

```
public class CompanyRepository : ICompanyRepository, IDisposable
{
    public CompanyRepository()
    {

    }

    private readonly IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;
    public CompanyRepository(IEmployeeRepository parameter)
    {
        _employeeRepository = parameter;
    }
    //fails never hits this
    private readonly ISalesRepository _salesRepository;
    public CompanyRepository(ISalesRepository parameter)
    {
        _salesRepository = parameter;
    }

}
```

MVC 5 Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    //works
    var a = _CompanyRepository.GetCompanyData();
    //works
    var b = _CompanyRepository.GetEmployeeData();
    //fails
    var c = _CompanyRepository.GetSalesData();

    //return view etc
}
```

App_Start Unity.Config

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        // register all your components with the container here
        // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

        container.RegisterType<ICompanyRepository, CompanyRepository>();
        //this one is failing
        container.RegisterType<ICompanyRepository, CompanyRepository>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<SalesRepository>()));
        container.RegisterType<ICompanyRepository, CompanyRepository>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(EmployeeRepository)));


        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

    }
}
```

I was just using but it is not working either

```
container.RegisterType<ICompanyRepository, CompanyRepository>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(SalesRepository)));
container.RegisterType<ICompanyRepository, CompanyRepository>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(EmployeeRepository)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should name your InjectionConstructor registrations

```
container.RegisterType<ICompanyRepository, CompanyRepository>("salesRep", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<SalesRepository>()));

container.RegisterType<ICompanyRepository, CompanyRepository>("employeeRep",new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<EmployeeRepository>()));
```

And then resolve like this

```
var salesRep = container.Resolve<ICompanyRepository>( "salesRep" );

var employeeRep = container.Resolve<ICompanyRepository>( "employeeRep" );
```

An alternative to resolving is to change your constructors to

```
public CompanyRepository([Dependency("employeeRep")]IEmployeeRepository parameter)

public CompanyRepository([Dependency("salesRep")]ISalesRepository parameter)
```

and then use the DependencyResolver